# modify content of xml file from published code

Tags: iis, filesystems, asp.net, publish

I am trying to modify an xml file from my aspx code. The file is in another directory from my project like in D:\folder\file.xml When publishing my code and running it I am receiving an error as not to be able to access this directory, access in denied. Which user account shall I add to this folder in security option to be able to modify it. I tried adding IIS user but it does not seem to work. Any other workaround this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which identity that's associated with the application pool, and grant that user access to the folder.

You didn't specify which version of IIS you're using, but here's a decent article on [how application pools work](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511/IIS-and-ASPNET-The-Application-Pool.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue finally..
In my pc I am using Win Xp and had to grant ASP.NET machine account user appropriate rights on the file while on the server that i am finally publishing the code I am using Windows Web Server 2008 and the matching ASP.NET Machine Account was Network Service i granted the same rights here and now i can modify the file successfully.
I am using IIS 7.5 on this machine.

I think your approach [Tchami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74183/tchami) has the same idea. So I am marking it as the answer :) Thank you